# arcpy.Select_management invalid sql expression - VDI

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, select-by-attribute, error-000358, virtual-machine

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 and trying to make separate feature classes from a larger feature class using a field delimiter and SQL statement but am getting an error that the SQL statement is invalid. Here is the snippet of code I'm having a problem with:

```
# This script looks at a featureclass(FC)/service location(SL)
# and splits it by day for web service data preparation.
# In this manner, end users can toggle off and on days of service.


#import modules
import arcpy
import os

#create input FC/SL -- the mega FC/SL
inputFC = raw_input("Paste Route FC from ArcCatalog: ")

#set default geodatabase
arcpy.env.workspace = raw_input("Paste default file GDB from ArcCatalog: ")

#designate output location as a variable so it can be used in system path
#output filename
outLocation = arcpy.env.workspace

# Designate the type of fleet, service, commodity etc
fleetType = raw_input("Name of output (e.g. Residential_Garbage, NO SPACES!!!): ")

#make a copy of the input FC so nothing gets corrupted
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputFC, "Copy_inputFC")

dayList = []
while True:
    day = raw_input("Type field delimiter and press enter. Type and enter 'Done' when finished: ")
    if day.lower() == 'done':
        break
    dayList.append(day)

#Make multiple FCs based on route number
for day in dayList:
    #Add field delimitters
    delimFld = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("Copy_inputFC", "Exist_Partition")
    print "step1"
    if day == '1':
        dayName = 'Monday'
    elif day == '2':
        dayName = 'Tuesday'
    elif day == '3':
        dayName = 'Wednesday'
    elif day == '4':
        dayName = 'Thursday'
    else:
        dayName = 'Friday'

    #Get output name
    outName = "{0}{1}{2}".format(fleetType,"_",dayName)
    outFC = os.path.join(outLocation, outName)
    print "step2", outFC

    #If routes are numbers:
    try:
        sql = "{0}={1}".format(delimFld, day)
        arcpy.Select_analysis("Copy_inputFC", outFC, sql)

    #If routes are strings
    except:
        sql = "{0} = '{1}'".format(delimFld, day)
        arcpy.Select_analysis("Copy_inputFC", outFC, sql)

    print outName


print "Finished"
```

This is what the error is saying:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "Exist_Partition" = '1'
Failed to execute (Select).
```

However, if I do the SQL statement in ArcMap it appears to be fine:

[image]

Comment: Is your Exist_Partition field numeric or text?

Comment: Have you reviewed questions tagged [tag:error-000358]?

Comment: "Exist_Partition" = '1' should be "Exist_Partition" = 'Monday' based on your code, perhaps it should be dayList.append(str(day)). I am assuming "Copy_inputFC" is a layer and Exist_Partition is a field (text) that exists in the layer... Can you include the line where the layer is made please.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I don't think that's quite right. The code clearly says to use 'day' not 'dayName'. The latter is used for the output name. Not the query, which prints out in the error message: ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "Exist_Partition" = '1'. I'm making the Feature layer with this: arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputFC, "Copy_inputFC")

Comment: @ShaunO Please [edit] your question to include additional information/clarification

Comment: You're right, I should have read it more thoroughly. Is there a reason why you're selecting against a layer and not the feature class directly? How does it go without the field delimiters? I don't use them when selecting, only during calculate field, I find they cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: @ PolyGeo I reviewed the posts for error 000358 after seeing your comment. I thought my statement was simple enough to only need the one pair of quotes around the .format elements. I haven't seen anything yet related to the sql I'm using but I will keep looking.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I thought that was the SOP when selecting by attributes but I guess I could do without it if I use Select_analysis instead of SelectByAttributes_analysis.

Comment: There's been debates on the best way to subset features; I wouldn't like to restart that argument. The error message is about the SQL syntax so I think we should concentrate on that rather than the tool... the reason I ask about layers is because it's possible to field-map an existing field out though that doesn't seem the case. The use of field delimiters, although advised, isn't manditory; like I said I don't use field delimiters  for where clauses and they work just fine, only instances like the target field in calculate field must have the field delimiter to work. So it's one thing to try.

Comment: @Midavalo included the rest of the code

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson yes, I thought the same thing about the field delimiters when I began editing this code (a lot of it was taken from another script I wrote last year). I'll give it a shot in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `Exist_Partition` doesn't actually exist in your layer.

From your screenshot it appears that your layer datasource is a Shapefile (I'm basing this on the presence of a `FID` field here).  A Shapefile has a maximum field length of 10 characters, however `Exist_Partition` has 15 characters.  When I tried to create that field in my Shapefile I was told it would be shortened to `Exist_Part` - 10 characters long.  The `arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters()` is also putting double quotes `" "` around the field name which it usually does on Shapefiles.

With my shapefile and `Exist_Part` field, I recreated your error message by using a trimmed down version of your code:

```
>>> delimFld = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("testpoints", "Exist_Partition")
>>> print delimFld
"Exist_Partition"
>>> day = "1"
>>> sql = "{0} = '{1}'".format(delimFld, day)
>>> print sql
"Exist_Partition" = '1'
>>> arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'
>>> outLocation = arcpy.env.workspace
>>> outName = "{0}{1}{2}".format("tester","_","Monday")
>>> outFC = os.path.join(outLocation, outName)
>>> arcpy.Select_analysis("testpoints", outFC, sql)

Start Time: Mon Mar 27 18:10:15 2017
ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "Exist_Partition" = '1'
Failed to execute (Select).
Failed at Mon Mar 27 18:10:15 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0.01 seconds) 

>>>
```

The expression is Invalid because the field `Exist_Partition` does not and can not exist in a shapefile.

This doesn't explain why it works when you enter it into the Select by Attributes window though - this does seem odd to me.  The screenshot doesn't show double-quotes `" "` around the field names in the Select by Attributes window though, which mine does on my shapefile.

Comment: I suspect that a shorter field name (like your `Exist_Part`) in the shapefile has an alias of `Exist_Partition` in the layer and map.  That way the Select_analysis on the shapefile is using a long field name that does not exist while the Select By Attributes in the map is using it as an alias instead, and so works.

Comment: @PolyGeo I had thought that, however the select by attributes didn't accept it in longer alias form when I tried it

Comment: That's curious.  I think the best way forward may be for the asker to try and reduce the size of his code snippet while keeping the error, and then see what extra step removes the error.

Comment: @Midavalo It's a featureclass, not a shapefile, however is it possible that the field name is truncated when converted to a feature layer? That is what the select analysis is being performed on. I'll add a print statement to print field names.

Comment: @ShaunO what type of feature class? Is it in a geodatabase of some sort? What kind? Usually the AddFieldDelimiters only adds the quote marks onto fields in shapefiles, not geodatabases. Try removing the field delimiters and force the sql to be `sql = "Exist_Partition = '1' "` with no quotes around the field name.

Comment: @Midavalo It is in a file geodatabse but it's working fine now. Turns out it was a field mapping problem on my VDI.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the script again this morning and it worked perfectly. I added `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`after setting the workspace with the user prompt. I took it out for testing and was receiving the error with it included so I'm confident it's unrelated to the problem. Otherwise it's exactly the same as my original post.

What was causing it was field mapping issues on my citrix VDI. The program either reads the directory where the data is stored as C:\RS_Data\Workspace or N:\Workspace. They are actually the same location depending on if you navigate through ArcMap or Windows Explorer, respectively.

This drive lives on a server with ArcMap and all of it's associated programs installed on it. Everything else I use is on a citrix server which I access through VDI. The latter acts as my main desktop and I access ArcMap desktop through it, reaching a desktop through another desktop. A virtual one at that. In certain transactions Python can't find certain files because the path names get mixed up.

In short, the problem was solved by terminating my session and logging back on which remapped the drives and allowed the program to find the feature layer.

I apologize for the long schpeil but I hope this will help others that encounter issues using ArcMap on VDI. I also added a virtual machine tag to the post. Thanks to everyone who helped me troubleshoot this.